# How to add a unique message on page redirect using PHP

Tags: php, forms, message

I know this question is simplistic, I am still learning.

I am trying to determine wether a user has filled out a form. The form submits to a function.

The function looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $newuser_values = $_POST['register'];

    foreach ($newuser_values as $key => $value) {
        if("" == trim($value])){
            .....
        } 
    }    
}
```

'register' is an array of values from the form.

I am trying to decide what to put inside the ....
I know I want to redirect to the form but I would like to somehow pass along a message to the form and display it so that the user will know what was wrong. What strategy do I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect successful form submission to another page in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478701/how-to-redirect-successful-form-submission-to-another-page-in-php)

Comment: I may of have read the link incorrectly but I don't think it is a duplicate. Difference is that I want to display a unique message for every form submission error (there can be many) on the original form. I know how to redirect to another page.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I've adjusted your question title a little to be more clear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You should put HTML form and PHP code on same file. Then,

You can do it by just `echo "Enter value";` inside if block... But your this PHP code should be at position where you want to display the error msg.

**OR**

Store error msg in a var: `$err="Enter value";`

And then write `<?php if(isset($err)) echo $err; ?>`, where you want to display error.

---

**(2) The approach above works when your HTML form and form processing PHP code** *(you mentioned above)* **should be on same coding file.**

***If you have two different file and want to redirect to the HTML form page with error msg then:***

There are many methods, but easiest is, write `header("location:formPageName.**php**?err=Enter Value");` inside if-block. [PHP code should be on top of page]

Then on formPageName.html write `<?php if(isset($_GET["err"])) echo $_GET["err"]; ?>`, where you want to display the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been working on this. I am now getting it to redirect to the page with the ?err=Enter Value suffix. It is still not echoing $err though. Here is what I have in my php funcion: if("" == trim($value)){
   $err = "Enter".$key;
      header("location:".get_permalink(51).".html?err=".$err);
  }

Comment: @bob This code is correct BUT what's the code on redirected page to echo error??? it should be `<?php if(isset($_GET["err"])) echo $_GET["err"]; ?>` NOT `echo $err;` its working here...

Comment: I tried it with quotes like you say. <?php if(isset($_GET["err"])) echo $_GET["err"]; ?>                          Could it be something to do with wordpress?

Comment: @bob its simple PHP, should also work in wordpress. Any error is there?? (inside PHP code you don't need again <?php ?>) | **For debugging type** `echo $_GET["err"];`, without if(isset()) condition then see the error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response it looks like the following works: header("location:formPageName.html&err=Enter Value");

Comment: @bob here I want to add a point that, it should be a PHP page(as we are echoing err) OR your server is set to process PHP code in a HTML file also...